# If statement SQL day of month interval

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I need to find in tables 'Contas' the next bill (Bills day: 5, 15, 25, 28), the problem is If we're in day 30, 'NEXT' statement won't find anything, it should return '5'.

I tried this without success

```
$"IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Contas WHERE Dia >= {Dia_Atual_LB}) SELECT * FROM Contas WHERE Dia >= {Dia_Atual_LB} ELSE SELECT * FROM Contas WHERE Dia >= 0"
```

It returns:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do what you want using `ORDER BY` and `TOP`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM Contas
ORDER BY IIF(Dia >= {Dia_Atual_LB}, 1, 2),  -- current/future days first
         Dia;
```

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning before, but I'm using VB.NET, I tried "$"SELECT TOP (1) * FROM Contas ORDER BY IIF(Dia >= {Dia_Atual_LB}, 1, 2)" and it returned me this:
"The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.'"

Comment: @HeitorBadotti . . . Remove the parens around `1`.  I don't think MS Access likes them.

Comment: Your statement work perfecly, but I was trying to understand it, I didn't get the part of  ", 1, 2)" what that means?

Comment: @HeitorBadotti . . . That is adding an `order by` key whose value is "1" for future dates and "2" for past dates.